# R Can we convert a matrix whose essential is list to a matrix whose essential is character vector?

Tags: r, list, matrix

Matrix is kind of vector with dimensions,I can create a matrix

```
m = matrix(list(rep(character(0),4)),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
```

whose essential is list with dimension:

```
str(m)
List of 4
...
- attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 2
```

I want to convert this matrix to a matrix like:

```
m = matrix(rep(character(0),4),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
```

whose essential is a character vector with dimension:

```
str(m)
chr [1:2, 1:2] NA NA NA NA
```

This convert is crucial because many function can deal with vector easily and return you a simple vector but these function itself can't handle list(unless you using apply/lapply which gives you a list result,after several operation you get a list wrapped by a list by another list)

Comment: why are you doing `character(0)`?

Comment: `rep(character(0),4)` is a vector of length 0 (not 4), so `matrix(rep(character(0),4),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)` doesn't really make sense (hence the `NA`). You seem to want to convert something which makes sense (though is unmotivated) to something which makes no sense at all. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: There is a good chance that this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835). Perhaps there is another way of solving your underlying problem, which doesn't involve creating matrices of `NA`. By the way, I don't think that your question deserved the downvote. It was reasonably clear (though a bit odd) and gave enough for others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to convert a list matrix to a char matrix, the data is our company's and I can't put it here, so I use character(0), you can use matrix(list("a","b","c","d"), nrow = 2,ncol = 2) instead, if you want

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have figured out how to convert a list matrix to a character matrix:
here is my step:

```
#initialize
m = matrix(list(rep(character(0),4)),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
#convert to dataframe to fortify its' 2 col 2 row shape
m = as.data.frame(m)
#unlist it and fill into the 2 col 2 row shape in data.frame
m[] = lapply(m,function(x){sapply(x,function(y)
{ifelse(length(y)==1,y,NA)})})
#convert it to matrix
m = as.matrix(m)
```

or put it more simple:

```
m2 = matrix(character(0),nrow = nrow(m),ncol = ncol(m))
m2[] = sapply(m,function(x){ifelse(length(x)==1,x,NA)})
```

only problem is the matrix's character(0) has change to NA, which I think is a good point, the essential meaning is the same and for NA we have more way to deal with

And @John Coleman has an opinion I think is also memorable, that a problem may has another easy path to solute, I am also thinking about it myself and if I get a solution I will also post here. But regarding this problem itself,it is solved.